# Beamer: same colour in the upper part

Tags: beamer, color

this code will create two kinds of colours in the upper part of each frame. How can I have only one colour, namely the deep blue?

The code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,11pt,mathserif]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Berlin}          % main theme
%\usecolortheme{lily}      % outer colour
\usecolortheme{rose}       % inner colour
\useoutertheme{infolines}     

\author{PSK} 
\title{Presentation} 

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Part I}
\begin{frame}{1st Frame}
 In this presentation ...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infolines outer theme sets

```
\setbeamercolor*{section in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{subsection in head/foot}{parent=palette primary}
```

and the color you want is governed by `palette tertiary` so the quickest solution would be to set

```
\setbeamercolor*{subsection in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=palette tertiary}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,11pt,mathserif]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Berlin}          % main theme
%\usecolortheme{lily}      % outer colour
\usecolortheme{rose}       % inner colour
\useoutertheme{infolines}     

\setbeamercolor*{subsection in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=palette tertiary}

\author{PSK} 
\title{Presentation} 

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Part I}
\begin{frame}{1st Frame}
 In this presentation ...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How can we have deep blue in the part that says 1st Frame as well? Is that possible?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis Please see my updated answer.